# Progress Dialog with For Loop

Tags: android

How can I use Progress Dialog box with for Loop.

Means either inside the loop or outside the loop wherever it's possible.
Currently I'm trying to use loop inside the progress dialog with it's not working.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    param = filename + "|" + String.valueOf(Outlet) + "|" + String.valueOf(UserId) + "|" + remarks + "|" + String.valueOf(rowid) + "|" + String.valueOf(ReportId);
    final String params = param;
    try {
        result = connectFTP();
        if (!result) {
            dbase.DeleteAlbum(rowid);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Record not uploaded.. Try Again..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            return;
        }
        if (result) {
            result = wcf.InsertAlbum(params);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: for(int i =0; i<4; i++)
{ param= filename + "|" + String.valueOf(Outlet) + "|" + String.valueOf(UserId) + "|" + remarks + "|" + String.valueOf(rowid) +"|" + String.valueOf(ReportId);
     
final String params = param;
try
{
result = connectFTP();
if(!result)
{
dbase.DeleteAlbum(rowid);
Toast.makeText(this,"Record not uploaded.. Try Again.." , 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
return;
}
if(result)
{
result = wcf.InsertAlbum(params);
}
      }
    
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}

Comment: @developer It would be better if you edited that into the original question and encapsulated it in code tags.

Comment: @staticbeast it's already a part of original question.I want to show the progress dialog while loop is in process. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  For the progress dialog to display, your main thread needs to be running its message loop.  The way you do work is to use AsyncTask or another facility to do that loop on a different thread.